# Remix warning - Is constant but potentially should not be.

Tags: solidity, remix, compilation, constant, warnings

I am getting the warning on the code shown below. Could you please assist me know to resolve this warning ?

**warning message - "Is constant but potentially should not be"**

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not applicable anymore. Remix does not report the warning message anymore, it was probably a bug in the analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Same [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3094) is discussed here but did not reach any conclusion.

I think this is happening because of `new` keyword while creating variable `string abcde`.

I have tried two example contracts for the confirmation.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Foo {
    uint256 n = 10;
    function initArray() public view  {
        uint[10*10] memory result;
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++){
           for(uint j = 0; j < n; j++){
                result[(i*9)+j]=1; 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For the above smart contract, remix doesn't throw a warning `Is constant but potentially should not be`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Foo {
    uint256 n = 10;
    function initArray() public view  {
        uint[] memory result = new uint[](n*n);
        for (uint i = 0; i < n; i++){
           for(uint j = 0; j < n; j++){
                result[(i*9)+j]=1; 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

However, for the above contract remix throws the warning:  `Is constant but potentially should not be.`

Answer (score 0):

The function writes to a state variable `babcde[]` defined elsewhere. Since it writes to the state, the read-only `pure` modifier is probably in error.

Hope it helps.